# mkdir in windows multiple path in single command

Tags: windows, command-line, mkdir

```
@echo off
set "var=string"
set "today=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%"
set "path_backup=\\SGSINWPDFS01v\SG\OTHERS\IT\OTHERS\WORKSTATIONS\SCHEDULE"
set "path_sourcepst01=AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook"
set "path_sourcepst02=Desktop"
set "path_sourcepst03=My Documents\PST"
set "path_sourcepst04=My Documents\Outlook"
set "path_sourcepst05=My Documents\Outlook Files"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst01%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst02%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst03%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst04%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst05%"
```

I modified the scripts as follow above.
I still the system still can't create the folder at sourcepst01, 03, 04 and 05.
The sourcepst02 is working fine.

It seem I can't MKDIR whole path, the system confused and must do one by one.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: FYI you don't need the first `mkdir` command. `mkdir` automatically creates all folders in the requested path.

Comment: ...and you could consider appending ` 2>nul` to the `mkdir` lines to suppress `directory already exists` message(s) should `cmd` feel that you need to be notified.

Comment: @AndrewMedico No it doesn't worked. It doesn't allow to create second path.

Comment: You are creating them on a network machine.  Do you receive an "Access is denied" error?

Answer (score 12):

Add the line:

```
setlocal enableextensions
```

just after the `@echo off` line of the batch file.  That will enable `mkdir` to create any intermediate directories.

An excerpt of output from `help mkdir`:

```
If Command Extensions are enabled MKDIR changes as follows:

MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
For example, assume \a does not exist then:

    mkdir \a\b\c\d

is the same as:

    mkdir \a
    chdir \a
    mkdir b
    chdir b
    mkdir c
    chdir c
    mkdir d

which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled.
```

Comment: I wouldn't think that that would matter, but I can never be sure of all the quirks in batch file commands.  Also, as Magoo mentions in another comment, command extensions are normally enabled by default. So if `setlocal enableextensions` ends up helping, you might want to read the output of `help cmd` to see how it can be disabled and fix that problem.

Answer (score 7):

Put quote marks around the paths.

```
mkdir "%foo%\%bar%\%somename%"
```

The problem is that the names have spaces in them, and mkdir is interpreting them as two arguments instead of a single name.  The quote marks will force it to interpret everything as a single path.

Comment: Yes, it does.  Clarify the error message you receive if it doesn't work for you,

Answer (score 2):

John Deters has nailed the problem - but I'd suggest

```dos
set "path_sourcepst4=My Documents\Outlook"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\PST-%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%\%path_sourcepst4%"
```

Using the `set "var=string"` format will ensure that the value set into the variable does not include any stray (and largely invisible) trailing spaces on the line. You only need to be caught out by that one once... It also reduces the number of <kbd>"</kbd> being resolved.

And why not set a variable called say `yyyymmdd` to `%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%` so that *that* string isn't repeated?

Comment: I added the new variables:
@echo off
set "var=string"
set "today=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%"

But still doesn't work on the second path after %today%

Comment: `set "var=string"` is a general statement-format. `set "today=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%"` is a specific instance of that format where *var* is `today` and *string* is `%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%` which means "the contents of `date`, from position 10 for 4 characters"-"the contents of `date`, from position 7 for 2 characters"-"the contents of `date`, from position 4 for 2 characters". (the first character is in position `0`). This is assigned to the variable `today`. The enclosing quotes ensure any trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned.

Comment: Michael Burr's response makes a lot of sense. In a tiny minority of cases, someone has deliberately turned off the enhanced faciities incorporated in `CMD` since 1996. By default, those extensions are enabled and it's normal to make the assumption that extensions ARE enabled.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
set "var=string"
set "today=%date:~10,4%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%"
set "path_backup=\\SGSINWPDFS01v\SG\OTHERS\IT\OTHERS\WORKSTATIONS\SCHEDULE"
set "path_sourcepst01=AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook"
set "path_sourcepst02=Desktop"
set "path_sourcepst03=My Documents\PST"
set "path_sourcepst04=My Documents\Outlook"
set "path_sourcepst05=My Documents\Outlook Files"
subst b: "%path_backup%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst01%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst02%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst03%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst04%"
mkdir "%path_backup%\%username%\%today%\PST\%path_sourcepst05%"
subst b: /D
```

I found the issue, it seem on network drive can't be created multiple level subfolders.
So map to local drive solve the issue.

Comment: What kind of server is the network share on (if you know)?  I can create multiple directories with a single `mkdir` on a UNC path here, so I wonder if it's the network server that's causing the glitch?

Comment: I've also encountered this issue where the `mkdir` command will not create nested directories in a single command on a mapped network drive.  I'm not sure why it won't but then again we're talking about Microsoft -- am I right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to the nested level of folder depth.

I believe that 8 levels of directory was the supported maximum, with a total length of 260 characters being another limit.

Comment: I haven't heard of an 8 level directory limit, but maybe that depends on the network?  The pathname looks like it should be well under 260 characters.

Comment: Maybe it was a FAT32 limit?  I just tried it in an NTFS local drive and I created a 9 level deep folder ok.